# Form field validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

As I already have validators in my models, so I think that duplicate them in the JS is not a viable way.
What are the options to run user input against Rails validations inside Ember App?

Comment: by `run user input against Rails validations inside Ember App` do you mean you have server side Regular Expressions that you want to reuse?

Comment: not yet :) just do not want to maintain same validations in both frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations for the Ember.js validations and https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-ember to bootstrap your client validations from your server validations.